# Why am I getting this IndexOutofBoundsexception?

Tags: android, arraylist

```
package org.example.mbtiapplication;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MBTITest extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener   {

    int I, E, N, S, T, F, J, P;
    String[] type;
    ArrayList<String> Evaluator = new ArrayList<String>(4);
    Spinner firstSpinner ;
    Spinner secondSpinner ;
    Spinner thirdSpinner;
    Spinner fourthSpinner ;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_mbtitest);
        firstSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        secondSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
        thirdSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner3);
        fourthSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner4);
        type = new String[3];
        addItemsOnSpinner1();
        addItemsOnSpinner2();
        addItemsOnSpinner3();
        addItemsOnSpinner4();
        final Button calculate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.calculate);
        calculate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                getPersonality();
                evaluateType();
                TextView calculatedPersonality = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.personalitytype);
                calculatedPersonality.setText(type.toString());

            }
        });


        }

    public void addItemsOnSpinner1(){   
        Spinner firstSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.spinnerarraybool, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        // Apply the adapter to the spinner
        firstSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);


    }

    public void addItemsOnSpinner2(){   
        Spinner firstSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
        // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.spinnerarraybool, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        // Apply the adapter to the spinner
        firstSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    public void addItemsOnSpinner3(){   
        Spinner firstSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner3);
        // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.spinnerarraybool, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        // Apply the adapter to the spinner
        firstSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    public void addItemsOnSpinner4(){   
        Spinner firstSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner4);
        // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.spinnerarraybool, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        // Apply the adapter to the spinner
        firstSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    }



    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View arg1, int arg2,
            long arg3) {
        switch (arg1.getId()){
        case R.id.spinner1:
            String firstAnswer = firstSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
            Evaluator.remove(0);
            Evaluator.add(0 ,firstAnswer);
            break;
        case R.id.spinner2:
            String secondAnswer = firstSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
            Evaluator.remove(1);
            Evaluator.add(1, secondAnswer);
            break;
        case R.id.spinner3:
            String thirdAnswer = firstSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
            Evaluator.remove(2);
            Evaluator.add(2, thirdAnswer);
            break;
        case R.id.spinner4:
            String fourthAnswer = firstSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
            Evaluator.remove(3);
            Evaluator.add(3, fourthAnswer);
            break;
        }


    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


    //Evaluates answers 
    public void getPersonality(){
        if (Evaluator.get(0) == "True"){
            E += 1;
        }
        if (Evaluator.get(0) == "In the Middle"){
            E += 1;
            I += 1;
        }
        if (Evaluator.get(0) == "False"){
            I += 1;
        }


        if (Evaluator.get(1) == "True"){
            N += 1;
        }
        if (Evaluator.get(1) == "In the Middle"){
            N += 1;
            S += 1;
        }
        if (Evaluator.get(1) == "False"){
            S += 1;
        }


        if (Evaluator.get(2) == "True"){
            F += 1;
        }
        if (Evaluator.get(2) == "In the Middle"){
            F += 1;
            T += 1;
        }
        if (Evaluator.get(2) == "False"){
            T += 1;
        }


        if (Evaluator.get(3) == "True"){
            P += 1;
        }
        if (Evaluator.get(3) == "In the Middle"){
            P += 1;
            J += 1;
        }
        if (Evaluator.get(3) == "False"){
            J += 1;
        }

    }

    public void evaluateType(){
        //INTRO VS EXTRO
        if (E > I){
            type[0] = "E";  
        }
        if (I > E){
            type[0] = "I";
        }
        if (I == E){
            type[0] = "x";      
        }
        //INTUITION VS SENSING
        if (N > S){
            type[1] = "N";  
        }
        if (S > N){
            type[1] = "S";
        }
        if (S == N){
            type[1] = "x";      
        }
        //THINKING VS FEELING
        if (T > F){
            type[2] = "T";  
        }
        if (F > T){
            type[2] = "F";
        }
        if (T == F){
            type[2] = "x";      
        }
        //JUDGING VS PERCIEVING
        if (J > P){
            type[3] = "J";  
        }
        if (P > J){
            type[3] = "P";
        }
        if (P == J){
            type[3] = "x";      
        }

    }











}

11-25 16:55:22.154: E/AndroidRuntime(1840): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-25 16:55:22.154: E/AndroidRuntime(1840): Process: org.example.mbtiapplication, PID: 1840
11-25 16:55:22.154: E/AndroidRuntime(1840): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
11-25 16:55:22.154: E/AndroidRuntime(1840):     at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
11-25 16:55:22.154: E/AndroidRuntime(1840):     at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
11-25 16:55:22.154: E/AndroidRuntime(1840):     at org.example.mbtiapplication.MBTITest.getPersonality(MBTITest.java:136)
11-25 16:55:22.154: E/AndroidRuntime(1840):     at org.example.mbtiapplication.MBTITest$1.onClick(MBTITest.java:43)
11-25 16:55:22.154: E/AndroidRuntime(1840):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4424)
11-25 16:55:22.154: E/AndroidRuntime(1840):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18383)
11-25 16:55:22.154: E/AndroidRuntime(1840):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
11-25 16:55:22.154: E/AndroidRuntime(1840):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
11-25 16:55:22.154: E/AndroidRuntime(1840):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-25 16:55:22.154: E/AndroidRuntime(1840):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
11-25 16:55:22.154: E/AndroidRuntime(1840):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-25 16:55:22.154: E/AndroidRuntime(1840):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-25 16:55:22.154: E/AndroidRuntime(1840):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
11-25 16:55:22.154: E/AndroidRuntime(1840):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
11-25 16:55:22.154: E/AndroidRuntime(1840):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Sorry for the nooby question.  I am a beginner programmer and have ran into another exception.  I have tried to mess with my ArrayList code and method .get() but to no avail I am here again.  This happens when I click on my button 'calculate.'  Any theories?

Comment: You should have learned how to read stack traces from your last question. `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
11-25 16:55:22.154: E/AndroidRuntime(1840):     at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
11-25 16:55:22.154: E/AndroidRuntime(1840):     at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
11-25 16:55:22.154: E/AndroidRuntime(1840):     at org.example.mbtiapplication.MBTITest.getPersonality(MBTITest.java:136)` what is line 136?

Comment: I understand where the problem lies, I'm just to noob to figure it out how to fix it!  Line 136 is whitespace

Comment: OK, this is getting annoying, A stack trace will NEVER reference an empty line.  Exactly as last time - post the actual code with the matching stack trace.

Comment: Simon, this is the actual code with the actual stacktrace, I made sure to double check

Comment: Then your editor is giving you incorrect line numbers.  Stack traces quite simply cannot reference whitespace lines.  Line 136 contains executable code.  If you are using IDEA or Studio (I think Eclispe does this to) you can simply click on the line in the logcat view and jump directly to the source line.  Either way, you or your editor are wrong in the assertion that line 136 is empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call new ArrayList(4), you are setting the list's initial capacity, not its size.

**So when you call:**

```
  Evaluator.get(0)
```

you are calling a get on an empty list.

You have to either add items to the list or make a check to see if the list contains items before calling get().

**Adding items:**

```
Evaluator.add(""); \\times 4
```

**Checking size:**

```
if(Evaluator.size()>0)
{
    //your code here
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
ArrayList<String> Evaluator = new ArrayList<String>(4);
```

This doesn't give you an ArrayList of 4 items

Try changing

```
ArrayList<String> Evaluator = new ArrayList<String>(4);
```

To

```
ArrayList<String> Evaluator = new ArrayList<String>(4);
Evaluator.add("");Evaluator.add("");Evaluator.add("");Evaluator.add("");
```

You see where the problem is now?

Answer (score 1):

I had a brief look at your code:

Your `Evaluator` is an `ArrayList` of `String`s. That means that it's size may vary dynamically during runtime. In your `onItemSelected` method you use the `remove()` method, which decreases the size of your `ArrayList`. Suppose your `ArrayList` only has 3 `String`s: you cannot call `Evaluator.get(3)`, because that would point to the 4th element, which you don't have.

Here's some plain Java code that you can run and understand:

import java.util.ArrayList;

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> evaluator = new ArrayList<String>(4);


        evaluator.add("A");
        evaluator.add("B");
        evaluator.add("C");
        evaluator.remove(0);

        System.out.print(evaluator.get(2));
    }
}
```

It will give your the following output:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 2, Size: 2
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:604)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:382)
    at Main.main(Main.java:14)
```

Once you remove a node from the `ArrayList`, it's size will drop from 3 to 2. So you cannot access the 3rd element by calling `get(2)`.

Comment: Immediately after I can the .remove() on my ArrayList, I apply a .add() method to the same index that I removed to make up for the lost space.

Comment: Yes, that's true. But for future reference, you need to know that the size of an ArrayList is dynamic, so you cannot assume it's going to have size you think.

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is in the

```
type = new String[3];
```

it should be

```
type = new String[4]
```

This is because an array starts at 0 and not 1. I see that you are trying to add 4 items to the array.

Comment: So how come the index is 0 and the size is 0?  This demonstrates that the OP is referencing an empty array.

Comment: Perhaps...i'll try it out, I always thought even when stating how many elements in an element, you take into consideration that it starts at 0.

Comment: You do, but the exception shows size=0.  Size is human readable and starts at 1, index starts at 0.